# Building AST from T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, parsing

Is it possible to parse T-SQL in exactly the same way as done by the SQL Server?

I suppose there is some code that SQL Server uses to build an AST from the given T-SQL. Is this code available for general audience?

Comment: [Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.transactsql.scriptdom.aspx) and example [A Program to Find INSERT Statements That Don’t Specify Columns](http://michaeljswart.com/2017/02/a-program-to-find-insert-statements-that-dont-specify-columns/)

Comment: I'll bite .... what's an AST?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree

Comment: @lad2025 - please, arrange as the answer and I will credit you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.transactsql.scriptdom.aspx)

> **The Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom namespace provides Microsoft SQL Server-specific Parser and Script Generator support.**

Example: [A Program to Find INSERT Statements That Don’t Specify Columns](http://michaeljswart.com/2017/02/a-program-to-find-insert-statements-that-dont-specify-columns/)